# Super+1, Super+2, Super+3, etc. keys can not be remapped in Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

I have been using the [gTile](https://github.com/gTile/gTile) Gnome shell extension. In gTile, I defined specific preset window positions, along with the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. to apply them. This was all working fine until a recent update of Gnome. After the update, some of my shortcuts now seem to do other random things, while other shortcuts don't seem to do anything at all.

I looked in *Settings → Devices → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts*, but the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> shortcuts didn't even seem to be defined. I also uninstalled all other Gnome shell extensions (thinking that other extensions might be setting their own shortcuts) but that didn't help.

**Why are these shortcuts un-remappable and how can I make them remappable again?**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/968103/42720

Comment: It would be so nice to have a way to remap those conveniently directly from the dock - ideally not matching the slot but the application itself (e.g. Super+F for Firefox, Super+T for Thunderbird, Super+G for Gedit/Geany...). It would be a the ideal replacement for the clumsy and sometimes buggy script I currently use with custom shortcuts.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It turns out that some keyboard shortcuts in Gnome do not show up in *Settings → Devices → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts*. These "hidden" shortcuts are accessible by using the `dconf-editor` command. In the dconf editor, the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> remapping was found at

`org/gnome/shell/keybindings/switch-to-application-1`

while remappings for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, etc. were found at similar locations. By clearing these mappings I was able to redefine my own.

[image]

*[related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066942/hidden-key-bindings-specifically-ctrlaltd-and-shiftsuper)

Comment: Thank you! Simply setting these to default (right click, `Set Default`) made it so I can use `Super+1`, `2`, etc. again. Tested on Pop!_OS 20.10.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was driving me crazy. The funny thing is that there are apparently the same defaults for all of `Super+1`, `Super+2` etc, but only `2` didn't work for me, i.e. it always was consumed by the shell itself instead of switching to the second workspace, while my custom screenshots did work for the other workspaces. Still no idea why, but at least I could make it work by resetting the value of this one to `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer, I am using the `dash-to-dock` extension and this extension also rebinds <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>.

What worked for me is also changing the

```
org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/app-hotkey-{0-9}
```